# Shell: get wildcard of files in all subdirectories except one?

Tags: directory, wildcard, glob, subdirectory

I have a tree that looks like this:

```
src/
├── engine/
├── python/
└── scenes/
```

I know that I can use `ls src/**/*` to get a list of files in all of `src`'s subdirectories, but I don't want to output any files in the `src/engine/` directory. Is there a concise way I can exclude `engine/` from the wildcard?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you're using Python since the question contains a reference to the directory `Python`. If you're not, then please ignore this answer.

You can use [Formic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/formic) with Python 2.6

From the command line, `formic` can be used like this to achieve your goal (assuming you are currently in `/path/to/src`:

```
formic -e "/engine/**"
```

The `-e` option excludes one (or more) Globs. In this case `/engine/**` excludes everything under the `engine` directory directly in your current working directory.

In Python:

```
import formic
fileset = formic.FileSet(include="**", exclude="/engine/**", directory="/path/to/src")
```

Formic uses paths relative to the working directory - this might be the parent of `src`, but if not, I suggest using a fully qualified path. In the example above, the search starts at `src` and includes everything (`**`).

Formic follows Ant's rules where a bunch of files are excluded (such as Git/Mercurial/CVS/SVN working directories). You can switch off this behaviour with the extra argument `default_excludes=false`.

You can specify multiple includes and excludes by passing a list rather than a string.

Disclosure - I am the author of this package.